# Reaction between Salicylaldehyde and 2-Benzoylpyridine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, heterocyclic-compounds

In a paper by Sheng et al (10.1016/j.dyepig.2018.07.036) the authors synthesize the compound MZC as shown in the scheme below. 
[image: Reaction scheme]

I'm looking for information about what the reaction mechanism is that underpins this reaction. If anyone can share some insights it is much appreciated.

In the experimental section  it is written

> 2-Benzoylpyridine (4 mmol, 0.732 g) and ammonium acetate (22 mmol, 1.70 g)
>   was dissolved in acetic acid (30 mL) and followed by the addition of salicylaldehyde
>   (6 mmol, 0.733 g). The reaction was refluxed for 6 h. The resulting solution mixture
>   was cooled to room temperature and cold water was then added to the mixture. The
>   solid was collected by filtration and washed with a small amount of cooled water,
>   which was purified via recrystallization using acetonitrile to give MZC (0.687 g, 60 %
>   yield).

Comment: Treat it step by step. For example, step 1: what does a ketone form when mixed with ammonia?

Comment: I assume that ammonium acetate $\ce{H3COONH4}$ provides for $\ce{NH3}$ in the reaction mixture. Ammonia will react with the ketone group in 2-Benzoylpyridie and form an imine, and that gives a hint on how an additional nitrogen enters the ring system. So the question then is, does the imine reacts with the aldehyde group in Salicylaldehyde?

Comment: The reaction is run in refluxing acetic acid so that is forcing conditions. Imines are not as nucleophilic as amines but they are stiil nucleophiles.

Comment: Technically, the reaction is one pot, so the order is not 100% certain. But you could also reasonably form the aldimine first on reactivity grounds (though the reaction is likely under Curtin-Hammett kinetics). Then keep in mind that the pyridine is relatively nucleophilic. I quickly tried drawing this out, and it seems feasible.